# Onclick action: two functions; only first working. Quite desperate

Tags: javascript, function, class, styles

This is my html code:

```
<td width="15%" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit"     class="button" 
   value="Basic" tabindex="13" 
   onclick="return submit_Click('bxbas','bxsht');" /></td>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_Click(aclass,bclass) {
  var elementsa = document.getElementsByClassName(aclass);
  for(i in elementsa)
  {
      elementsa[i].style.display = "block";
  } 
  var elementsb = document.getElementsByClassName(bclass);
  for(j in elementsb)
  {
      elementsb[j].style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Apparently, only the first part of the function is working, the one that makes the first class (aclass) to be shown. The second one remains visible.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any error on the console?

Comment: What is the html of the elements that are supposed to be changed

Comment: alejandro-bar, I don't know how to see that. I use Chrome...

Comment: deme72, the class is for a row of a table. If I write first the "none" loop, it works for "none" and not for "block". If I write first the "block" loop, it works only for "block" and not for "none"...

Comment: ok, the message from the console is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Don't use For.. In in this case. If you Console.Log your elementsa you'll see that the last element is a not a number, so it breaks your elementsa[i]. Using "for" solves the problem:

```
function submit_Click(aclass, bclass) {
        var elementsa = document.getElementsByClassName(aclass);
        for (i=0; i < elementsa.length; i++) {
            elementsa[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        var elementsb = document.getElementsByClassName(bclass);
        for (j=0; j < elementsb.length; j++) {
            elementsb[j].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.THAT'S the answer.